# Programmatically send commands to an interactive REPL from Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, process, read-eval-print-loop

Is it possible to programmatically enter some repl (say `mongo`), and programmatically interact with it? That is to say, can you do this programmatically:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
> db.collections
test.collections
> exit
bye
```

All that does is:

1. Login to the REPL with the `mongo` command. I know it's possible to do this somehow, I have seen it done to [create interactive REPL's in the Node.js world](http://maxogden.com/node-repl.html). It would be helpful to know how to do this in bash directly.
2. Once logged in, I typed `db.collections`, just exploring the REPL. This SO question is asking, can you do *this* programmatically? Like can you perhaps (a) create a child process/REPL from a bash script, and then (b) send it arbitrary messages like this `db.collections`, which it evaluates. (And can you get the response/output back).
3. Programmatically log out of the REPL.

Is this possible?

Comment: search here for Qs using "Here-Docs" (delimited by `<< EOS .... cmds ... EOS` (Unfotunately, `EOS` can be any arbitrary string, so sometimes you see `<< _` or `<< EOD`, or << ...` (a dozen other things.). Focus on "Here-Documents" and do small tests to see if `mongo` can read from them. Else look at `expect`. Good luck.

Comment: as shellter, said, use [here document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument). If that does not work (some commands do not allow redirected `stdin`), go for [`expect`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/expect/) based solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will check those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) script which will interactively input those commands for you. I'm not a regular expect user but I think it should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
mongo
set timeout 10
expect "MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8"
send "db.collections"
expect "test.collections"
send exit
```

There are a lot of examples out there which should make it easy to create a minimal working example.